# Basketball throw-in - deflected inbound pass

Tags: rules, basketball

Player A inbounds the ball but Player B knocks the ball back at him.

Player A is still out-of-bounds when the batted ball hits him.

Is it Team A's ball because Player A never became a "live" player?

Is it Team B's ball because the ball hit him as he was standing out-of-bounds?

Answer (score 1):

According to [(NBA) Rule 8-Section II-c](http://www.nba.com/analysis/rules_8.html):

> The ball is caused to go out-of-bounds by the last player to touch it before it goes out, provided it is out-of-bounds because of touching *something other than a player*. **If the ball is out-of-bounds because of touching a player who is on or outside a boundary, such player caused it to go out.** [My emphasis.]

The similar rule in the [(FIBA) Official Basketball Rules 2012](http://www.fiba.com/downloads/Rules/2012/OfficialBasketballRules2012.pdf) is:

> 23.2.2 If the ball is out-of-bounds because of touching or being touched by a player who is on or outside the boundary line, this player causes the ball to go out-of-bounds.

**So, the ball is now Team B's.**